# Could you explain these two javascript examples?

Tags: javascript

1: Why is the result of `foo && baz` not 1? Because true is 1.

```
var foo = 1;
var baz = 2;

foo && baz;   // returns 2, which is true
```

2: There are two pluses in the `console.log(foo + +bar);`, what's the meaning of them?

```
var foo = 1;
var bar = '2';
console.log(foo + +bar);
```

Comment: These are two very separate questions, probably should be separated.

Comment: This is javascript not jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the `&&` (*logical AND*) operator returns the value of the last operand it evaluated. Since `foo` is `true`, it has to evaluate `bar` to determine the outcome of the expression (it will only be `true` if `bar` is also `true`).

The opposite would happen with the `||` (*logical OR*) operator. In that case, since `foo` is `true`, the outcome of the expression is known to be `true` without having to evaluate `bar`, so the value of `foo` will be returned.

Concerning your second question, the unary `+` operator allows to convert the string `'2'` into the number `2`.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` returns the value of the last evaluated value. ´&&´ is a operator. Most of the time it used in a context like this

```
if ( something && somethingelse ) {}
```

in other words

```
0 && 2 //would return 0 because 0 is a falsy value
12 && 10 && 0 && 100 // would return 0 to 
10 && 123 && "abc" // returns "abc"
```

`+` is a mathematical operator but it can be used to convert a string in to a number.

```
1 + 1 = 2
1 + '1' = 11 //van damme would like this one
1 + +'1' = 2 // somce '1' got converted to a number
```

Comment: i don't think it was ment for that, but it works. You could simply use parseInt('1') for example

Answer (score 2):

Javascript follows [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So according to this, javascript returns the last value if both the values are true